# (NODE JS ) How Redirect Unauthorized express-acl to view ejs

Tags: node.js, express, acl

Consider [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkxya.png) error message. I rather want error to look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRyAB.png)

This my code:

```
let configObject = {
filename: 'nacl.json',
searchPath: 'session.user.title'
};

let responseObject = {
status: 'Access Denied',
message: 'You are not authorized to access this resource'
};
acl.config(configObject, responseObject);
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do this in express-acl without modifying this module. It's pretty simple, though. It has only two functions: `config` and `authorize`. The second one simply sets the 401 status code on res and sends a json containing your custom message when the permission constant is set to false or is undefined. You'd have to ask developers to add an option which would allow to redirect res instead of setting the 401 status code. You can do this yourself, though. Just modify the 77th line of code in `node_modules/express-acl/index.js` to your liking.

Comment: Actually, I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/nyambati/express-acl/issues/113) in their issue tracker, because I also had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, this feature wasn't available in express-acl. I've created a [PR](https://github.com/nyambati/express-acl/pull/114) and it was already merged. A new option called `denyCallback` will be added in the next release. Until then, you can use their [development branch](https://github.com/nyambati/express-acl) which includes the new changes. Here's an example:

```
const acl = require('express-acl');

let configObject = {
  filename: 'acl.json',
  path: 'config',
  denyCallback: (res) => {
    return res.render(`notAuthorized`);
  }
};

acl.config(configObject);
```